# DB2 syntax when running H2 (in DB2 mode) - year

Tags: h2

This question is kind of a continuation of this thread:
[DB2 syntax when running H2 (in DB2 mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339779/db2-syntax-when-running-h2-in-db2-mode)

We have a DB2 database in production, and is setting up a H2 in-memory database for tests. But not all DB2 syntax is respected by H2, even thus we of course have configured it to use DB2 mode.

The SQL in question is this:
select slutt_dato - 2 year as tDato from klv80201

H2 doesnt respect "year" keyword. Is there any equivialent for "Db2 year" in H2 ?

Answer (score 0):

For H2, one solution is:

```
select dateadd(year, -2, now())
```

See also the documentation of [dateadd](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) and related functions.